# SSRS scheduled report running on a different schedule than was setup

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

SQL Server 2008 (not R2).

The report was setup on 5/8/2017 and scheduled to run every Monday every 4 weeks.  It ran again on 6/5/2017, which is correct.  It then ran again on 6/12/2017, which is only 1 week.  Then it ran again on 7/10/2017, which is 4 weeks.  Looking in the execution logs the username is sql.service and RequestType is Subscription for 6/5, 6/12 & 7/10.  In the Report Manager it says the schedule started on 5/8.  I don't see anything that is indicating the schedule changed.

Any ideas why the report would run again on 6/12 when it wasn't scheduled to run?  Thanks!

Here's the schedule as it looks today.
[image]

Comment: My guess is to check the history of the SQL job agent for the subscription (not the actual log for the subscription) for the date 06/12/2017 and it may show who/how the job was executed.

Comment: Digging a little deeper I see the report was updated on 6/7/2017 to add another person to the email delivery - added another email address in the "TO".  Would that cause the schedule date to reset?  6/7 was a Friday and 6/12 was the following Monday.  If adding an email address and just clicking Save (no other changes) makes the schedule reset that would explain why it ran again on Monday 6/12.

Comment: CuriousKid - I checked the log and it was executed by sql.service as a subscription, no one manually ran it.

Comment: That may have caused the schedule change. When you look at the subscription schedule today does it shows the schedule start as 05/08 or 06/07? if it shows 06/07 then it looks like when the address in "TO" was added, the schedule  also changed and set the start schedule date to 06/07.

Comment: It still shows 05/08 as the schedule start.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the subscription settings?

Comment: It looks like the schedule has been reset on 06/07 that is the reason it executed on 06/12 and 07/10. if the schedule was same as old and if it was just one time then instead of 07/10 the report should have ran on 07/03. But i am not sure why start of the schedule still shows 05/08. Can you query MatchData column (xml) in the dbo.Subscriptions table and see what date shows in there for the StartDateTime[1] in the '/ScheduleDefinition' node.

Comment: use this query(change the xmlnamespace based on your version of report server):
`with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/03/01/ReportServer' as rs)
SELECT
[Description]
,m.value('rs:StartDateTime[1]','varchar(30)') AS StartDateTime
,m.value('rs:EndDate[1]','varchar(30)') AS EndDate
FROM
(
    SELECT
    [description],
    CAST(MatchData AS XML) AS MatchData
    FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
) AS P
CROSS APPLY MatchData.nodes('/ScheduleDefinition') x(m)`

Comment: StartDateTime and EndDate are null for all 17 rows.

Comment: Please look at one of the XML and see that the xmlnamespace you have. it should be like this: [http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/report‌​ing/2010/03/01/Repor‌​tServer](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/report‌​ing/2010/03/01/Repor‌​tServer) and replace. If you are not able to locate. please pase the first 2 lines of the xml here and i can send you the updated query.

Comment: I went to http://localhost/reportserver/reportdefinition.xsd, found the right namespace, replaced it and it's still returning null values.  (fyi, I replaced localhost with the correct server name).

Comment: Run this query for the subscriptions and check the startdatetime and enddatetime. 
`SELECT [description]
  ,CAST(MatchData AS XML) AS MatchData
 FROM ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions`

Comment: No luck, still null.  The namespaces I'm using is http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition which is odd because when I go into sql server and choose Help > About it says sql server 2008, and I made sure that reportdefinition.xsd was the same server.  select @@version says Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)   Mar 19 2015 12:32:14   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Look at the XML of the subscription and the XML should have the value of start time and end time. or can you paste the XML here?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the database to see what is going on with the report?

Something like following? :

```
USE ReportServer;
GO

DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(200)= '%'+'ReportName'+'%';

SELECT TimeStart,
       Catalog.Type,
       Catalog.Name,
       Catalog.Path,
       UserName,
       ReportID
FROM Catalog
     INNER JOIN ExecutionLog ON Catalog.ItemID = ExecutionLog.ReportID
WHERE Path LIKE @Path;
```

Comment: I already had that information.  On 6/7/2017 someone added another email address to the TO.  That was a Wednesday.  It then ran on Monday 6/12/2017.  My theory is when they made the change on 6/7 that reset the schedule - instead of the following Monday being week 2 it was now week 1 so it ran.  I told them next time they make a change like this to also change the "Begin running this schedule on" to the next date it is supposed to run, which in this case would have been 7/3/2017.

Comment: I don't know if this is really what happens, was hoping someone could tell me yes or no.  I'm going to test this with my local install.  Thanks for the help though, much appreciated!  :)

Comment: Welcome @Rich. Sometimes only the one who asked the question can solve the issue as all the systems, information and resources are in front of you. Best of luck.